# how to pic color of a specific point of bitmap and use this to compare a color code

Tags: android

i am trying to get the color of a specific point and want to compare it to the face color ,but i have the problem to compare it. how i compare it to the color of black and white face
because at the black and white face there are different core code for different faces.
 please help me find the color of face and to know where it is color of black and white or colored face.
i use Bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
but not able to compare it to know that it is color of black and white face or not.

please help.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about ur requirement bt following is the code to fetch color from a pixel

```
      int pixel = x.getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
                int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
                int c=Color.rgb(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
```

Now c is the color of that pixel